# How to delete KDE plasma desktop envivornment in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I installed Kubuntu on my PC, but didn't like the default KDE Plasma desktop environment. So I installed xfce desktop environment and I really liked it. So I want to now get rid of KDE. How do I do this?

Comment: Its better to not uninstall KDE desktop as many other applications depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt-get purge kde-desktop` then reboot and login to another desktop. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Login in your plasma desktop environment and then open terminal/konsole
and enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-full
sudo apt-get remove plasma-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then reboot the system and you can enjoy XCFE desktop environment.